# Receive Undefined class constant 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATE' when use filter

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, dbal

I'm using API platform v2.5 with Symfony 5.4 and php7.4.
I'm tried to create filters with official documentation: https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.5/core/filters/ , but when I try to use filter on datetime property, the error occur.

Here is my filter definition:

```
* @ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties={"valid_to": "include_null_before"})
```

here `valid_to` is property in my entity. I tried to omit properties, but it doesn't have any effect.

I also tried to setup this filter in yaml configuration

```
//config/services.yaml
...
myentity.date_filter:
    parent: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.date_filter'
    arguments: [ { valid_to: "include_null_before"} ]
    tags: [ 'api_platform.filter' ]
```

I'm expecting, that the filter works.

Comment: In the current version of DBAL, there is a Types::DATE_MUTABLE and a Types:DATE_IMMUTABLE.  No just plain DATE.  I'm guessing you have a version msimatch of some sort between the api platform and dbal.

Comment: thank you Cerad, it was exact the problem. 
Solution: update doctrine/migrations to ^3.4  and doctrine/dbal to ^2